# Variable programs and variable data

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

I'm reading "Sets for Mathematics" by Lawvere, and he uses the following metaphor at the end of section 1.3: "we will see...how any abstract set F of the right size can act as mappings between given abstract sets. (For example, in computers variable programs are just a particular kind of variable data.)"

The internet seems silent on these so called "variable programs". Has anyone heard of them/has an accessible introduction (at an introductory graduate level)? Extra bonus points if you can explain how this relates to sets and functions.

Comment: Maybe they mean self-modifying code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the authors refer to "functions as first-class variables". In functional languages you have variables which store functions. You can think of them as *program variables* since they store programs. On the other hand, if you look at how the programs are stored physically, then you get unstructured *variable data*.

Let's be more concrete. The (somewhat functional) programming language Python has a function `eval` which takes as argument a Python program. Consider the following code:

```
prog = "sum([x for x in range(5)])"
print eval(prog)
```

This prints $10$ (since in Python `range(5) = [0,1,2,3,4]`). Here `prog` is a *program variable* since it stores a program. On the other hand, `prog` is also just a mundane string (*variable data*). From the point of view of Python, unless you try to evaluate it ("cast" it into a program), `prog` is basically just a string.

If we use an enumeration of programs like in recursion theory, then program variables really are unstructured — they are just integers. If Python supported this convention then `prog` would be just some number with no apparent structure.

In the same way, a set-theoretic function is just another set, unless you treat it as a function. Given two sets $A,B$, we can construct the set which contains all mappings from $A$ to $B$; I don't quite understand why only the "size" (i.e., cardinality) of this set matters, but I guess you'll have to wait until Chapter 5. Perhaps they mean that with the correct encoding function, every set of the correct cardinality can be used as an *index set* for all mappings from $A$ to $B$, just like the enumeration of programs mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, and seems to fit in with the section. I think the size is the only thing that matters only because all sets of the same cardinality are "set isomorphic". I guess, like you said, Chapter 5 may have more to say on that.